# Is there a WCF Request-specific scope I can use to cache a value?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm not talking about a session - this data wouldn't be persisted between requests. I have a deeply nested base constructor that I'd rather have accessing this scope for a piece of data rather than passing it through these long chains...

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the `Extensions` property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733816.aspx) of `OperationContext` - which is easily accessible via its static `OperationContext.Current` property (only within the scope of an operation, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the direction. With your help, I was able to dig up this helpful link as well: http://hyperthink.net/blog/a-simple-ish-approach-to-custom-context-in-wcf/

Answer (score 3):

You can expose the cached object as a property on your service class. Then, from anywhere in the call chain you will be able to access this service class using OperationContext.Current.[InstanceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.instancecontext.aspx).[GetServiceInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575343.aspx)()

```
MyServiceImplementation service = (MyServiceImplementation)OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance();
var cachedValue = service.MyCachedValue;
```

This is assuming that you're using SingleCall instancing, as opposed to session-based or singleton instancing.